# How to optimize SQL query with window functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, query-optimization

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222889/how-to-calculate-power-consumption-from-power-records/) one. I have table which contains power values for devices and I need to calculate power consumption for given time span and return 10 most power consuming devices. I have generated 192 devices and 7742208 measurement records (40324 for each). This is roughly how much records devices would produce in one month.

For this amount of data my current query takes over 40s to execute which is too much because time span and amount of devices and measurements could be much higher. Should I try to solve this with different approach than lag() OVER PARTITION and what other optimizations can be made? I would really appreciate suggestions with code examples.

PostgreSQL version 9.4

Query with example values:

```
SELECT
  t.device_id,
  sum(len_y*(extract(epoch from len_x))) AS total_consumption
FROM (
    SELECT
      m.id,
      m.device_id,
      m.power_total,
      m.created_at,
      m.power_total+lag(m.power_total) OVER (
        PARTITION BY device_id
        ORDER BY m.created_at
      ) AS len_y,
      m.created_at-lag(m.created_at) OVER (
        PARTITION BY device_id
        ORDER BY m.created_at
      ) AS len_x
    FROM
      measurements AS m
  WHERE m.created_at BETWEEN '2015-07-30 13:05:24.403552+00'::timestamp
    AND '2015-08-27 12:34:59.826837+00'::timestamp
) AS t
GROUP BY t.device_id
ORDER BY total_consumption
DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Table info:

```
    Column    |           Type           |                         Modifiers
--------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
 id           | integer                  | not null default nextval('measurements_id_seq'::regclass)
 created_at   | timestamp with time zone | default timezone('utc'::text, now())
 power_total  | real                     |
 device_id    | integer                  | not null
Indexes:
    "measurements_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "measurements_device_id_idx" btree (device_id)
    "measurements_created_at_idx" btree (created_at)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "measurements_device_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (device_id) REFERENCES devices(id)
```

Query plan:

```
Limit  (cost=1317403.25..1317403.27 rows=10 width=24) (actual time=41077.091..41077.094 rows=10 loops=1)
->  Sort  (cost=1317403.25..1317403.73 rows=192 width=24) (actual time=41077.089..41077.092 rows=10 loops=1)
Sort Key: (sum((((m.power_total + lag(m.power_total) OVER (?))) * date_part('epoch'::text, ((m.created_at - lag(m.created_at) OVER (?)))))))
Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
->  GroupAggregate  (cost=1041700.67..1317399.10 rows=192 width=24) (actual time=25361.013..41076.562 rows=192 loops=1)
Group Key: m.device_id
->  WindowAgg  (cost=1041700.67..1201314.44 rows=5804137 width=20) (actual time=25291.797..37839.727 rows=7742208 loops=1)
->  Sort  (cost=1041700.67..1056211.02 rows=5804137 width=20) (actual time=25291.746..30699.993 rows=7742208 loops=1)
Sort Key: m.device_id, m.created_at
Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 257344kB
->  Seq Scan on measurements m  (cost=0.00..151582.05 rows=5804137 width=20) (actual time=0.333..5112.851 rows=7742208 loops=1)
Filter: ((created_at >= '2015-07-30 13:05:24.403552'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2015-08-27 12:34:59.826837'::timestamp without time zone))

Planning time: 0.351 ms
Execution time: 41114.883 ms
```

Query to generate test table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE measurements (
    id          serial primary key,
    device_id   integer,
    power_total real,
    created_at  timestamp
);

INSERT INTO measurements(
    device_id,
    created_at,
    power_total
  )
SELECT
  device_id,
  now() + (i * interval '1 minute'),
  random()*(50-1)+1
FROM (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT(device_id),
    generate_series(0,10) AS i
 FROM (
  SELECT
    generate_series(1,5) AS device_id
  ) AS dev_ids
) AS gen_table;
```

Comment: How about a composite index on (device_id, created_at) ? BTW, IMHO you should divide `m.power_total+lag(m.power_total) ` by two before usage. (Or just take the average)

Comment: +1 Best question I have seen in a long time. Very well written, proper sample. I create the sample db in a sec. Now what values should I put in the `series` to generate a db similar to your current size?

Comment: Your `where` condition does not remove any rows. Is that intended? The sorting is also done on disk: `external merge  Disk: 257344kB` which takes pretty long as (your execution plan lost the indention so it's a bit hard to read). If you increase the `work_mem` for the session until the sorting is done in memory, you should see better performance.

Comment: This is what I get when I create an index on `(device_id, created_at)`: http://explain.depesz.com/s/7XSj

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes that was intended in this demo case. Thanks for memory tip. Increasing work_mem from default 4MB to 10MB got me to 35s . I also tried higher values but those only slowed the execution time. With 820MB I was able to achieve `Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 798633kB` execution time was 55s.

Comment: @joop Yes I left that for back end to do because it won't effect to comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to move some part of the calculations into the phase of row insertion.

Add a new column:

```
alter table measurements add consumption real;
```

Update the column:

```
with m1 as (
    select
        id, power_total, created_at,
        lag(power_total) over (partition by device_id order by created_at) prev_power_total,
        lag(created_at) over (partition by device_id order by created_at) prev_created_at
    from measurements
    )
update measurements m2
set consumption = 
    (m1.power_total+ m1.prev_power_total)*
    extract(epoch from m1.created_at- m1.prev_created_at)
from m1
where m2.id = m1.id;
```

Create a trigger:

```
create or replace function before_insert_on_measurements()
returns trigger language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    rec record;
begin
    select power_total, created_at into rec
    from measurements
    where device_id = new.device_id
    order by created_at desc
    limit 1;
    new.consumption:= 
        (new.power_total+ rec.power_total)*
        extract(epoch from new.created_at- rec.created_at);
    return new;
end $$;

create trigger before_insert_on_measurements
before insert on measurements
for each row execute procedure before_insert_on_measurements();
```

The query:

```
select device_id, sum(consumption) total_consumption
from measurements
-- where conditions
group by 1
order by 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Using this approach I was able to achieve 9s execution time. BTW it should be ordered by 2nd column. =)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is a different one.

I create the sample data with 8 M rows (200 device, 40000 measures)

and response is really fast (2 seconds)

Postgres 9.3  - iCore 5 / 3.2 mhz / 8gb / sata Hdd / Windows 7 
I didn't create index yet ( you miss that part in your setup script )

[image]

Comment: Did you make sure the `where` condition does not filter out any of the 8 million rows? Because that's what happening in the original query. If I run the sample with 8million rows, it takes about 12 seconds (which is still faster than the original timing)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I did just copy select from OP question. Will check again.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Why you say Isn't filtering any rows? Inner select with `WHERE m.created_at BETWEEN '2015-07-30 13:05:24.403552+00'::timestamp
    AND '2015-08-27 12:34:59.826837+00'::timestamp` bring 5800 rows, without that `where` the select bring the 8M records and take 300 seconds.

Comment: In the original plan there is no `Rows Removed by Filter:` step below the `Seq Scan on measurements`. That's an indicator that the `WHERE` condition didn't remove anything.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name without the `where` the whole query take 22 sec. Still less than 40 sec. Will test the index now.